# Replace carriage returns between [[ .... ]]

Tags: regex, perl, text, sed

I have a file that looks like:

```
[[ this is a test
this is a line
this is another line]]
```

I want it to look like:

```
[[this is a test~this is a line~this is another line]]
```

if I use single [ it works.. with:

```
perl -ane "s/\R/~/ if (/\[/ .. /\]/) && !/]/;print $_ unless $_ =~ /~\s*\^s*$/;" < filename.txt
```

How can I modify this to use double [[ ]] 
I'm having to use double as a divider as I learned some of the text contained single ] which was closing it when it didn't need to be. I have confirmed that no double [[ exists in the files.

Comment: Did you try anything? `/\[\[/ .. /\]\]/` doesn't sound too hard.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a novice with this! that worked perfect!

Comment: Can I ask you one more question on this...   now if I want to clean all of the [[  ]] out of this file.. how could I do that?

Comment: You would remove them with a substitution. Before the `print`, just do `s/\[\[|\]\]/;` to remove one pair of either opening or closing brackets from the current line. You can get rid of the `&& !/]/` by using `...` instead of `..` and all `$_` and `=~` btw.

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're having trouble with regular expressions and regex operators, I would recommend reading the [official Perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: @JasonHamrick: Please don't ask additional questions in comments on Stack Overflow. Every question should be self-contained. It's also best not to offer someone else's code as if it were your own unless you understand it inside-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include both brackets in your patterns for the flip-flop operator `..`.

```
/\[\[/ .. /\]\]/
```